# Should I withdraw from a graduate math class to make more time for a promising research project?

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate, withdraw

I am a junior graduating May 2021 with a double major in physics in math, and I will be applying to commutative algebra (math) graduate programs this upcoming fall. I was recently offered an unexpected but very promising commutative algebra research project, but because the research is time sensitive and needs to be completed by May, I would need to withdraw from my graduate complex analysis course to complete it. I am wondering if it would be worth taking the 'W' on my transcript in order to gain a (very likely) publication. I've been mulling the decision over for over a week now and am desperately seeking some advice. Here is some background:

- I am enrolled in 5 graduate courses (4 math, 1 CS) and a thesis writing class.
- I have participated in math research and presented it at conferences, but am not currently published.
- I have completed 4 graduate math classes in the past.

I tried cutting other commitments to avoid withdrawing from a class, but discovered that I just don't have enough time for my classes and research. Basically, I'm trying to gauge whether one more graduate math class or one more research project (albeit with a 'W' on my transcript) will make me appear more competitive to graduate admissions boards. Complex analysis is currently my largest time commitment – I am not confident that I can withdraw from anything else and still make enough time for research.

Comment: There’s absolutely no question: a paper is far better than one more graduate course. Assuming you do manage to publish it, it’s a fine reason to get a ‘W’.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks a bunch, that's what I suspected, but needed reassurance. There is, of course, inherent risk involved with publishing, but that's a risk I'm willing to take. Thank you!

Comment: What does your thesis advisor say?  Their advice is likely to be better informed than ours.

Comment: Be careful taking advice from non-mathematicians (like knzhou).    Undergraduate research plays far less of a role in math PhD admissions than in the other sciences.  This kind of question cannot be answered in the abstract, so you *need* to talk it over with a mentor who knows your situation in detail and also knows a lot about math grad school admissions.

Comment: @NoahSnyder My advisor's have given me waffling advice, and have said that either option is fine. When I mentioned that I was leaning towards withdrawing, one of my advisors recommended withdrawing and explaining the reasons for the withdrawal in my applications. I haven't received feedback on how a 'W', particularly one in complex analysis, will affect me.

Comment: @AndyPutman Thank you for the advice Dr. Putnam, I will talk it over again with my advisors in that case.

Comment: I'm very confused about where the May deadline comes from.  Is this for a CS conference?

Comment: As an aside, the possibility of unexpected opportunities arising outside of class is a good reason why your high courseload would usually be considered inadvisable.

Comment: @NoahSnyder I was offered the project by a post doc whose position ends in May. He is unwilling to mentor me remotely, hence the deadline. I could, however, potentially find another mentor.